# linux args list too long error

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run this command, but get arg list too long error:

`find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5 -name *.cdb -type f -mmin +30 -delete`

Error is:

```
/usr/bin/find: Arg list too long.
```

Probably the find command returns too many files.
Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should escape the asterisk to prevent the shell from expanding it:

```
find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5 -name \*.cdb -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

or

```
find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5 -name '*.cdb' -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) is expanding your `*.cdb` argument and you are sending too many arguments to the `find` command.

Try adding quotes to that argument to avoid shell expansion and pass the globbing task to the `find` command:

```
find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5 -name '*.cdb' -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

If you still need to increment the maximum arguments limit, you can use `ulimit -s`:

```
ulimit -s 65536
```